# Cannot change column 'role_id':used in a foreign key constraint 'users_role_id_foreign'(SQL:ALTER TABLE users CHANGE role_id role_id INT DEFAULT NULL)

Tags: phpmyadmin, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

> SQLSTATE[HY000]:General error:1832 Cannot change column 'role_id':
>   used i n a foreign key constraint 'users_role_id_foreign' (SQL: ALTER
>   TABLE users CHANGE role_id role_id INT DEFAULT NULL)

voyager version : v1.1
laravel : v5.7

I made changes in seeders and re-seed the database
run this command
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
I was phasing this error

Screenshot
[image]

2017_11_26_013051_add_user_role_relationship_fix.php. this file is there in migration everything in commented in run() and down() method.

how to solve this please anyone can help me

Comment: can you share migration file

Comment: when edit seeder i need to run php artisan db:seed ??den seed refresh ?

Comment: In Client.php line 1371:

  Operations quota exceeded, change plan to get more Operations.

when i am doing seeding i am phacing this

Answer (score -4, accepted):

just run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` instead